What is the difference between direct effect and correlation in factor analysis?
I am reading the short course material of factor analysis from:
https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2016/10/harvard-lecture-series-session-4_Factor-analysis.pdf#page=38.00

Here, the author mentioned that there is an oblique case, where the interpretation of loading will be different from the orthogonal case:
The interpretation of factor loadings is no longer a correlation between Y and F; it is a direct effect of F on Y.
Is it related to DAG? e.g. F1>F2>Y2, so some indirect effect of F1 may not be measured in loading?

I think that by direct effect the author meant simply the clean effect of F1 on Y2, the effect that is cleared from the effect of F2 on Y2 (F1 and F2 correlate).

This thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/166799/3277 might be worth reading.
